# Change href attribute for certain element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".link").click(function() {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(".textarea").offset().top-220
        }, 700, function(){jQuery( ".textarea" ).focus();});
    });
});
```

and I want it to work exactly as it is after clicking

```
.link
```

but after clicking a link on certain page (.page-1 being a body class of this page)

```
.page-1 .link
```

I don't want it to animate scroll and focus, instead I only want to change href attribute of

```
.page-1 .link
```

is it possible?

Comment: `if ($(this).hasClass("page-1")) { change href } else { animate }`

Comment: What is `.page-1`? Where it exists in your html?

Comment: it's a body class of certain page

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it either by using one click handler for all `.link` or by using separate ones for the different page classes

Using one and checking body class inside event handler:

```
jQuery(".link").click(function() {
   if(jQuery('body').hasClass('page-1')){
      jQuery(this).attr('href', 'new-href-value');
   }else{
      // do the animation
   }
});
```

Or by checking page class before creating event listener:

```
if(jQuery('body').hasClass('page-1')){

   jQuery(".link").click(function() {   
      jQuery(this).attr('href', 'new-href-value');
   });

}else{
   jQuery(".link").click(function() {   
      // do animation
   });
}
```

or by using different selectors:

```
   jQuery(".page-1 .link").click(function() {   
      jQuery(this).attr('href', 'new-href-value');
   });

   jQuery(".link").not('.page-1 .link').click(function() {   
      // do animation
   });
```